# Reference on Gibbs phenomenon

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series

I need a reference that explains the following result (also known as the Gibbs phenomenon)

> Let $g$ be a $2\pi$-periodic function, $C^1$ per pieces (i.e., there exists a partition $x_1 < \cdots < x_n$ such that $g$ is $C^1$ in $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$) and suppose that $g$ is discontinuous on $x_i \forall i=1,\ldots,n$.
>
> If $S_n(x)$ is the $n$'th Fourier partial sum of $g$ and $\delta_{i,n}=x_i+\frac{\pi}{n+1}$, we have:
>
> $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n(\delta_{i,n})=\frac{1}{2}(g(x_i+0)+g(x_i-0))+\frac{\nu}{\pi}(g(x_i+0)+g(x_i-0))$, where $g(x_i+0)$ is the right limit of $g$ in $x_i$ (analogous for $g(x_i-0)$) and $\nu = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Usually you write $g(x_i^+)$ and $g(x_i^-)$ respectively, since $+0$ and $-0$ are technically irrelevant.

Comment: Folland's textbook _Real Analysis_ addresses it. It suffices to consider the Heaviside function, because the general piecewise $C^1$ function is the sum of a Lipschitz function (for which the series converges uniformly) and a bunch of Heavisides.

Comment: Hardy and Rogosinski  _Fourier Series_  page 36- 37 section 3.12 particularly the last paragraph explains precisely this limit.